# Can someone tell me what this datasheet is trying to tell me?

Tags: audio, serial, data

This datasheet is for an audio delay IC that i plan on using:
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpa5052.pdf

I understand everything pretty clearly except some important details that i've circled in this screen shot photo:
[image: Screen shot of datasheet I2S description]

The blue circles i've made are supposed to be data as far as i know, but they seem to be deliberately stopping short of the left/right word change. Why? I've read this entire datasheet over and over and can't figure out why they stop short.

Also (yellow circles) it's trying to use left and right arrows and a full clock pulse to tell me something... again with no info regarding it. Please help!

Comment: data is from MSB to LSB. data sent in the blue circle area is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

N bits of data are  sent starting on the rising clock edge of BCK which occurs 1 clock cycle after the change of LRCK level (= yellow circle). ie there is a 1 x BCK cycle needed to deal with the prior data block before new clocking will start.
 N bits of data are sent MSB first.
 After N bits have been sent the data is latched into the IC by changing LRCK state on a BCK falling edge. The delay between the clocking in of the last data bit by BCK and the latching of the data word by LRCK changing is not specified in this diagram except that  it is at least a BCK half cycle (= blue circle).

A look at fig 1 shows more detail of timings.
 Data and LRCk can change together and BCLK occurs Tsu1 (= setup time) after data and LRCK have changed = 10 ns min.
 Data must be held after BCLK for time = Th1 ( = time hold 1 ) = 10 ns minimum.

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be a word select bit. In \$I^2S\$, it is possible to mix equipment which uses different bit lengths, so it's possible to send data from a 32bit device to a 24 bit device. The 24 bit device will only take its first 24 bits and then wait for the signal that the 32 bit device has finished sending. The word select bit also tells the receiver that the channel is switched.As you can see, there is one after left channel and then after right channel and then again after left channel and so on.

So I guess that in an asynchronous scenario, this would be probably called stop bit.